# Configuring Entity Framework Many to Many relationship between two tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to define a many to many relationship between two tables using code first on existing tables. The "State" table and class can not be modified so I am trying to find a way to make that relationship work in Entity Framework without modifying the table or class.

I have a table in SQL that is represented by the class:

```
 [Table("MySchema.Content")]
public class Content 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

I have a second table representing a list of States. (This class and table can not be changed)
The class is:

```
[Table("dbo.State")]
public class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

I have manually created a join table called `MySchema.Content_State` that contains `ContentID` and `StateID` as the two columns.

In my data context class I would like to use `ModelBuilder` to create the relationship but have not been able to figure out how to get it to work.

In the Context I've  tried something like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
           .HasMany<State>(a => a.States)
           .WithMany(a => a.Contents)
           .Map(a =>
           {
               a.ToTable("Content_State", "MySchema");
               a.MapLeftKey("ContentId");
               a.MapRightKey("StateID");
           });
```

The above won't compile, complaining about the WithMany line.

How can I configure this to work against my constructed join table?

Comment: WithMany(a => a.Contents)  I couldn't see the list in State.cs

Comment: That is the issue. I can not modify the State Class and Table, it has to stay as is.

Answer (score 1):

**your models**

```
  [Table("MySchema.Content")]
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContentState> ContentStates { get; set; }

}

[Table("dbo.State")]
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContentState> ContentStates { get; set; }

}

public class ContentState
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

**your mapping**

```
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                 modelBuilder.Entity<ContentState>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.StateId, bc.ContentId });


        modelBuilder.Entity<ContentState>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Content)
            .WithMany(b => b.ContentStates)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ContentId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ContentState>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.State)
            .WithMany(c => c.ContentStates)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.StateId);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Context I just changed the code to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
       .HasMany<State>(a => a.States)
       .WithMany()
       .Map(a =>
       {
           a.ToTable("Content_State", "MySchema");
           a.MapLeftKey("ContentId");
           a.MapRightKey("StateID");
       });
```